# ASHX image handler not working in ie, works in firefox and chrome

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, httphandler

I am storing images in a database and I am using an image handler to display the images using the file path + id. The problem I have is when I update the image through the page, the image doesn't change. Wierd thing is I don't have this problem with firefox or chrome.

ASHX handler

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Guid image_id;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            image_id = System.Guid.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Stream strm = GetImageFromDatabase(image_id);
        if (strm != null)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

            while (byteSeq > 0)
            {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
                byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            }
            //context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        }
    }
```

User control code

```
string imagePath = "<a href=" + (Image.ImageUrl = "~/ShowImage.ashx?id=" + r["Image_id"]);
```

Markup

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Upd1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="mpe" style="width: 600px; padding: 5px;">
            <uc2:IMG ID="IMG1" cssclass="bodycopy" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="upp1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="Upd1">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div id="progressBackgroundFilter">
                </div>
                <div id="modalPopup">
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; Loading...
                    <img align="middle" src="../images/Ajax/loading_1.gif" />
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am not sure what other code to post but here is what I think is relevant. When I click my button to update an image it successfully updates the row in the database. Also I can update data about an image and this correctly updates.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you check the page in **IE** using **developer tool** and check whether the image is there or not??

Comment: The image displays in ie on page loading its when I update an image that I see the old image and not the new image if that makes sense?

Comment: That probably due to caching.. Please have a look at this **http://superuser.com/questions/81182/how-to-force-internet-explorer-ie-to-really-reload-the-page**

Comment: I should also point out that when I remove the update panel this is problem doesn't exist. But I use update panel for update progress control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is using a guid as my image id in my Image handler. But in my SQL, when I update an image I use sql servers in-built newid() function so everytime an update is made that images guid will change. By doing this IE recognises that its not the same ID and doesn't use the cached image.

Answer (score 1):

IE caches the data and shows the same if the URL does not change. I was also facing the same problem and removed it with the following trick: -

```
imgUser.ImageUrl = "Handler.ashx?UserID=" + Convert.ToString(Session["userid"]) + "extraQS=" + DateTime.Now.Second;
```

The extraQS query string with DateTime.Now.Second will make the trick by making the URL dynamic and thus the URL will change on each request and the image will not be used from browser cache.

**Note: - Ignore the extra query string argument in Handler.ashx.**

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use this code?

```
string imagePath = "<a href='" + Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/ShowImage.ashx?id=" + r["Image_id"]) + "' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved by adding the current seconds or random number at the end of QueryString. Its works fine for IE.

```
string imagePath = "<a href=" + (Image.ImageUrl = "~/ShowImage.ashx?id=" + r["Image_id"] + "&timeInSec="+ DateTime.Now.Second);
```

> Another Example Which returns the Image URL

```
protected string getImageURL(int index)
        {
            return  "ImageHandler.ashx?index=" + index + "&timeInSec=" + DateTime.Now.Second;
        }
```